# Docker-Copmose.yml environment variable default value computation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a php docker image that I'm initiating from the docker compose with some additional containers.

I would like to enable the php remote debugging on the container and I don't want to have any hard coded configuration values.

the hard coded values works fine

```
services: 
    phpSite: 
        environment:
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=${MY_IP:-1.1.1.113}
```

I know that I can get my local ip from the ipconfig on my host name but I have failed to solve it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I deal with it using `make` by putting in my `Makefile` something like this:

```make
up:
    HOST_IP=$$(ip -4 addr show docker0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+') \
        docker-compose up
```

In `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services: 
    phpSite: 
        environment:
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=${HOST_IP}
```

Comment: do you know if it is possible also in docker for windows?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t have any experience with Docker on Windows. However, I think that is possible. Try to search for “get docker host ip on windows”.